# Override Linq-to-Sql Datetime.ToString() Default Convert Values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to override the default `CONVERT` style? I would like the default [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) function to always return ISO8601 style 126.

**Steps To Reproduce:**

```
DROP TABLE DATES;

CREATE TABLE DATES
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MYDATE DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE())
);

INSERT INTO DATES DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO DATES DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO DATES DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO DATES DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,MYDATE) AS CONVERTED, 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),MYDATE,126) AS ISO, 
       MYDATE FROM DATES
WHERE MYDATE LIKE'Feb%'
```

**Output:**

```
CONVERTED                   ISO                          MYDATE
--------------------------- ---------------------------- -----------------------
Feb  8 2011 12:17AM         2011-02-08T00:17:03.040      2011-02-08 00:17:03.040
Feb  8 2011 12:17AM         2011-02-08T00:17:03.040      2011-02-08 00:17:03.040
Feb  8 2011 12:17AM         2011-02-08T00:17:03.040      2011-02-08 00:17:03.040
Feb  8 2011 12:17AM         2011-02-08T00:17:03.040      2011-02-08 00:17:03.040
```

Linq-to-Sql calls `CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@p)` when I cast `ToString()`. However, I am displaying all my data in the ISO8601 format. I would like to override the database default if possible to `CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@p,126)`.

I am using [Dynamic Linq-to-Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) as demoed by [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to process my data.

```
PropertyInfo piField = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.field);
if (piField != null)
{
    Type typeField = piField.PropertyType;
    if (typeField.IsGenericType && typeField.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        filter = filter
           .Select(x => x)
           .Where(string.Format("{0} != null", rule.field))
           .Where(string.Format("{0}.Value.ToString().Contains(\"{1}\")", rule.field, rule.data));
    }
    else
    {
        filter = filter
            .Select(x => x)
            .Where(string.Format("{0} != null", rule.field))
            .Where(string.Format("{0}.ToString().Contains(\"{1}\")", rule.field, rule.data));
    }
}
```

I was hoping my property would convert the expression from `CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@p)` to `CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@p,126)`, however I get a `NotSupportedException: ... has no supported translation to SQL.`

```
public string IsoDate
{
    get
    {
        if (SUBMIT_DATE.HasValue)
        {
            return SUBMIT_DATE.Value.ToString("o");
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use dynamic linq I used an expression builder. See **Ilya Builuk's** *Using jqGrid’s search toolbar with multiple filters in ASP.NET MVC* found on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx). It builds expressions dynamically based on class parameters. Obviously I could not use "contains" but I could use greater than or less expressions.

You can substitute `WhereOperation` with a string. In this particular example it is a enum.

I implemented greater and less expressions and I was able to narrow my searches rather than using the words contains.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{  
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
        string column, object value, WhereOperation operation)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
            return query;

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in column.Split('.'))
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
               (memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);

        //change param value type
        //necessary to getting bool from string
        ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant
            (
                Convert.ChangeType(value, memberAccess.Type)
            );

        //switch operation
        Expression condition = null;
        LambdaExpression lambda = null;
        switch (operation)
        {
            //equal ==
            case WhereOperation.Equal:
                condition = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            //not equal !=
            case WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                condition = Expression.NotEqual(memberAccess, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            //string.Contains()
            case WhereOperation.Contains:
                condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    Expression.Constant(value));
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
        }


        MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
               typeof(Queryable), "Where",
               new[] { query.ElementType },
               query.Expression,
               lambda);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
    }
}
```